# Rails session store to persist search params between requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this is a frequent question, but I couldn't find it on this terms:

I have a main page table, with some category filters.
But as the user jumps from pages to pages inside my website, I want that when he returns to the main page, that the filters will still be checked as he did.
But would like to avoid storing that in the database for 3 reasons: #1: the public users can use that feature; #2: Avoid another model in the database; #3: Performance penalty to query another table on every index load.
What is the best way to achieve this? any example?
How can I do this?
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just set a session with the params then parse the params from the session when they return to the home page?